# Zero sum of squares

Tags: complex-numbers

I know that, for $x_i ∈ \mathbb R$,

$ 0 = \sum_{i=0}^n x_i^2$

iff $x_0=x_1=x_2=...=x_n=0$

However, if we consider $z_i ∈ \mathbb C$, does the same principle hold? Or rather, under what conditions would that principle hold?

**EDIT**: Just realized that...

For the case $n=2$, it is evident that if $\Re(z)= ± \Im(z)$ and if $z_2$ is the conjugate of $z_1$, the sum would be zero.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not true for $z_1 \in \mathbb{C} $

eg. $1^2 + \iota^2 =0$

for $z \in  \mathbb{C}$ you should use $|z|$

Answer (score 1):

For complex numbers it does not hold, for example if you take $x_1=1$ and $x_2=i$ then$$x_{1}^2+x_{2}^2=1+i^2=0$$ The property is preserve if you take the modulus instead of the square:$$|x_{1}|+|x_{2}|\ge0$$ or, in general:
$$\sum_{i=0}^n|x_i|\ge0$$ And it is zero only in the case $x_0=x_1=...=x_n=0$

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't hold for $x_i\in\mathbb{C}$. For instance, if $n=1$, I can put $x_0 = i$, and $x_1=1$, giving
$$\sum_{i=0}^n x_i^2 = i^2 + 1^2 = -1 + 1 = 0.$$
To answer under what circumstance it does hold is a bit broad. If $z_0,z_1,\ldots,z_n$ are complex numbers, then your result will be true for e.g. the real parts of the $z_i$, $x_i=\text{Re}(z_i)$, for the imaginary parts $x_i=\text{Im}(z_i)$, and for the modulus $x_i=|z_i|$.